# Record raw PCM from microphone

Tags: python, audio, c

I have a small project I'm working on that will use real-time audio processing. Until now I've been able to record (via the `arecord` command) straight to a `.wav`, but like I said I need real-time processing.

I would like to take a PCM stream from my microphone and pipe the output from that into another program (such as a spectrogram maker). What is the most effective way to achieve this?

Comment: Using what language?

Comment: Preferably Python but I guess C would be optimal.

Comment: So you just want code that will record a .wav file, right?  From there you will perform your own manipulations/processing?

Comment: No, not really. I want a code that „pulls“ PCM data from the mic and pipes it to another program in real-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I misunderstood your question initially.  Here is some C code that, when run, will record raw PCM data.  **You must pipe this to another program or lots of gibberish will be printed to the console.**

```
/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main()
{
    long loops;
    int rc;
    int size;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    unsigned int val;
    int dir;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
    char *buffer;

    /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
    rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "plughw:1,0", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open PCM device: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    /* Fill it in with default values. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

    /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

    /* Interleaved mode */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

    /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

    /* Two channels (stereo) */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

    /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
    val = 44100;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &val, &dir);

    /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
    frames = 32;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);

    /* Write the parameters to the driver */
    rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set HW parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
    size = frames * 4; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
    buffer = (char *) malloc(size);

    /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &val, &dir);
    loops = 5000000 / val;

    while (loops > 0)
    {
        loops--;
        rc = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
        if (rc == -EPIPE)
        {
            /* EPIPE means overrun */
            fprintf(stderr, "overrun occurred\n");
            snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
        } else if (rc < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error from read: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        } else if (rc != (int)frames)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Short read, read %d frames\n", rc);
        }
        rc = write(1, buffer, size);
        if (rc != size) fprintf(stderr, "Short write: wrote %d bytes\n", rc);
    }

    snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to grab sound from multiple microphones at once and in sync? Say I want to grab 44100 samples per microphone in 3 buffers *BUT* knowing that the samples are in sync.

Comment: @xeon I would just create multiple threads and then record a stream per thread, though I am unsure that this would be completely in sync because the Raspberry Pi only has one core.  Also, if you like my answer, you should up vote it. :)

Comment: I am a beginner, can someone please explain how to connect this to a spectrogram program?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "pipe" it to another program just write to stdout, not a file , e.g. in bash:

```
arecord - | aplay -
```

this line records audio and writes it to stdout, which is read by aplay (its stdin).

You can do the same by using *mkfifo*, which would act as "buffer" with which you can interact as typical file (as with stdout, stdin).